# PHP comparing all value inside column of multidimensional array with variable

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and a variable to compare:

```
$var = 1;
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 5
        'NumberAssigned' = 1
        ),
    n => array(
        'id' => 22
        'NumberAssigned' = 1
        )
)
```

I want to compare all of the value inside the `NumberAssigned` column in the multidimensional array with the variable, if all of the value in column match with the variable then `$var = $var+1`. What is the solution?

Comment: *what is the solution?* **What have you tried?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `array_column` to make the multidimensional array into a simple array. Use `array_unique` to get the unique values. If there are only 1 unique value and the value is the same with `$var`, all `NumberAssigned` are the same with `$var`

```
$var = 1;
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 5,
        'NumberAssigned' => 1
        ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 22,
        'NumberAssigned' => 1
        ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 23,
        'NumberAssigned' => 1
        ),
);


$num = array_unique(array_column($arr,'NumberAssigned'));

if( count($num) === 1 && $num[0] === $var ) $var++;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop.
Use array_column to get all values and remove duplicates with array_unique.
If the var is in the array and the count is 1 then all values match var.

```
$narr = array_unique(array_column($arr, "NumberAssigned"));

If(in_array($var, $narr) && count($narr) == 1){
    $var++;
}Else{
   // They are not all 1
}

Echo $var;
```

https://3v4l.org/k08NI

Answer (score 0):

You can force uniqueness by using the targeted column as first level keys.  As a concise technique when you don't need microoptimization, you can use:

```
if (count(array_column($arr, null, 'NumberAssigned')) < 2)
// true if $arr is empty or all values in column are the same
```

This won't be technically *fastest*. The *fastest* algorithm would allow an early return before iterating the entire set of data in the column.

```
function allValuesAreSame($array, $columnName) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        $result[$row[$columnName]] = null;
        if (count($result) > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // also true if $array is empty
}
```